# Any Java date picker for the Jalali Calendar?

Tags: java, localization, datepicker

Hi
I need a Jalali date picker to use in my Swing application.
Can you suggest me one?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/persiancalendar/) could help